# Customer creation qbxml Requests with custom values-quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I have been trying to create a customer in QuickBooks and I have to update the returned LISTID value in my database.For that Is there any way to send Id (for ex: customer id =101 which is in my database) using "sendrequestXML" and in "receiveResponseXML" , I want to return that customer id along with LISTID. So, that I can update the LISTID "8000002B-1502038359" for customer id "101 " in my database. I am using web connector and Qbxml.

> Here is my sample code

```
//Create CustomerAddRq aggregate and fill in field values for it
                    XmlElement CustomerAddRq = requestXmlDoc.CreateElement("CustomerAddRq");
                    qbposXMLMsgsRq.AppendChild(CustomerAddRq);
                    //Create CustomerAdd aggregate and fill in field values for it
                    XmlElement CustomerAdd = requestXmlDoc.CreateElement("CustomerAdd");
                    CustomerAddRq.AppendChild(CustomerAdd);
                    //Set field value for Name <!-- required -->
                    CustomerAdd.AppendChild(MakeSimpleElem(requestXmlDoc, "Name", "tarun"));

//How to send my database customer id value in the "sendRequestXML".
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use either the AccountNumber or more than likely need to use a custom data field to store this information. You will not be able to query directly against it.

Comment: Do I need to add "AccountAddRq" query along with customer creation or can I directly wrap account number inside the customer creation request.

Comment: I'm also trying to do what the asker needs.

I have successfully created a private field called 'RefID' to Customers and Invoices using the DataExtDefAddRq targeting Customer and Invoice objects, but wherever I try to add 'RefID' to my Customeradd or Invoiceadd requests, QBWC gives vague, and unhelpful errors, ie "QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream", followed by an XML dump of my request, with no additional information. The docs don't really tell you how to submit such private values with these requests.

Let me know if you figured this out, please!